# Flutter Web: How to run without a device/browser?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, web-development-server

I want to run the flutter web development server without specifying a device/browser.

Comment: Please update your question to clearly and concisely clarify what exactly you are asking about

Comment: I'm developing a web app with flutter & want to run the web server without having to install chrome or any other browser

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess you mean without specifying browser? If so you try running it with this command :

`flutter run -d web-server`

Answer (score -3):

You must to define chrome.

```
flutter run -d chrome
```

Check this documentation:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Comment: This is exactly what I didn't want to do